# How to get a specific column from a matrix in r？

Tags: r

I have a matrix as following, how can I extract the desired column with `[`？

```
MX <- matrix(101:112,ncol=3)
MX[,2]
# [1] 105 106 107 108
`[`(MX, c(1:4,2))
# [1] 101 102 103 104 102
```

Obviously, it does not extract 2nd column as intuitive guess, but honestly gets the 2nd element of all.

More like I am asking how to express MX[,2] with `[`.

Please advise, Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Keep the row index as blank

```
`[`(MX, ,2)
#[1] 105 106 107 108
```

or if we need to extract selected rows (1:4) of a specific column (2), specify the row, column index without concatenating.  `c` will turn the row and column index to a single `vector` instead of two

```
`[`(MX, 1:4, 2)
#[1] 105 106 107 108
```